# VECM "goodness of fit" in R

Tags: goodness-of-fit, r-squared, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I'm using ca.jo in R to perform the Johansen test on a given dataset.

I obtain my VECM coefficients, cointegration rank, etc.

However, it does not seem to give any notion of "strength of relationship" or "goodness of fit". So my questions are:

1 - What is a standard/reliable way to measure how strong the relationship is in a given VECM cointegration model?

2 - How do I obtain that measurement in R?